# How do you display a specific JS array element in the HTML input text Placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, placeholder

Let say I want to display the 45 element in the Students_C1 array in the placeholder. How should i do that ?

```
var Students_C1= [45,0,0,0,0];

 <input type="text" id="inputss" name="S1_C1" value="" placeholder="<**I want a specific JS array Elements Here**">
            <button style="display:none;" id="myButton" onclick="UpdateValues('inputss')">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('inputss').placeholder = Students_C1.join();`?

Comment: Alon Eitan.. How do you use that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
var Students_C1= [45,0,0,0,0];
document.getElementById('inputss').placeholder = Students_C1.join(", ");
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="inputss" name="S1_C1" value="" placeholder="<**I want a specific JS array Elements Here**">
 <button style="display:none;" id="myButton" onclick="UpdateValues('inputss')">Submit</button>
```